# zsugar zimlet in zimbra for https

Tags: sugarcrm, zimbra

Is it possible to integrate zsugar zimlet in zimbra for http sugar CRM as I found that this zimlet only work for secure connection(https). If yes then Please give me the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the SugarCRM Web Service API through both HTTP and HTTPS.